# Access a child page control with Javascript (asp.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a control with a listbox inside an updatepanel connected to a timer which is doing an autopostback with a scriptmanager on the main form.

To keep the item selected throughout the postback I use the below javascript. I have researched this quite thoroughly and don't believe there is another way to keep the selecteditem selected between postbacks. However this solution seems to work quite well.

My issue is that when I add a second control to the main form it won't work.

I have tried moving the javascript into the main form however I cannot access the child controls from the main form using:

```
document.getElementById('<%=PositionsControl.FindControl("ListBox_Candidates").ClientID %>').selectedIndex
```

I have also tried renaming the BeginRequestHandler and EndRequestHandler to unique names (to avoid conflicts when this script is on both control) and it will not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var index
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        index = document.getElementById('<%=ListBox_Candidates.ClientID %>').selectedIndex;
    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $get('<%=ListBox_Candidates.ClientID %>').selectedIndex = index;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with not using Microsoft Ajax and calling webmethods from jquery instead!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add property in code behind, that will return you value you need. 
Then, in client side, just bind to this property.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand can you explain what you mean please ie which property?

Comment: In code behaind (c#?) Add property, that will expose the value you need (selectedIndex). In javascript, bind to its value insread of control. Like <÷ = MyServerProperty ÷>

Comment: The control is currently binding properly. There is no problem with binding the control. The problem occurs when I have 2 of these scripts on the same page (registering 2 beginRequest event handlers).